# In Java how to design a method to systematically test different combinations of conditions?

Tags: java, combinations

If I have an app that has the following methods, what's the best way to come up with another method to systematically test different combinations of the conditions ?

So if I have something like these :

boolean A() { return (x-y/z > n-m/p) ;  }  // just to show an example

boolean B() { do some calculation and return either true or false }

boolean C() { do some calculation and return either true or false }

and I don't know which of the following results will benefit me the most, so I need to test all of them :

```
A() && B() && C()
A() || B() || C()
A() && B() || C()
!A() && B() && C()
A() || !B() || C()
A() && B() || !C()
A() || B() && C()
A() && ( B() || C() )
A() || ( B() && C() )
...
```

How to come up with a method like the following :

```
boolean Z(int Combo_Id,boolean A,boolean B,boolean C)
{
  switch (Combo_Id)
  {
    case 1 : return A && B && C;
    case 2 : return A || B || C;
       ...
  }
}
```

As you can see, I'll have to do them one by one, what if I have 10, 20 methods like A(),B(), F(),L() ... how to design a method to automatically test the different combinations of the conditions ?

Of course, I've omitted more details, each method like A() can take some parameters so it's like A(int P1,float P2), and so on, each of the combination will lead me to a different value of another parameter that I'm trying to find the best value of, but that's something else, the main question is how to automatically generate systematic combination.

Comment: Isn't the combination that benefits you the most simply the one that performs the calculation you intend?

Comment: How do you define "benefit you the most"? Each of the listed expressions will either yield true or false. Do you mean how to find one of the expressions that results in true?

Comment: You missed exclusive OR and NOT conditions.  I guess you can write a Java program to output your Z method.

Comment: It sounds like a very fun problem.  A hint:  it's all object-oriented; since Java (7) isn't going to allow you to pass around functions as first class objects, you'd abstract them away and do some sort of operation on them in a sequence.

Comment: As an idea, currently ignoring the possible braces: you have A or !A, then you have && or ||, then B or !B, then && or ||, then C or !C. So you have 5 positions, each with a binary decision. Iterating from 0 to 2^5 should give all the combinations if the bits are represented as the choices. then you could have something like: `if (bit0==0) a=a(); else a=!a(); if (bit3==0) b=b(); else b=!b(); if (bit2==0) ab = a&&b; else ab = a||b;` and so on.

Comment: @ cello : I was thinking on the same path ...